# Show this function defined on a smooth manifold is (not) smooth

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold and $U \subseteq M$ be a open subset such that there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: U \to B$ where $B$ is the $n$-dimensional open unit ball.

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a nonnegative smooth function such that $f^{-1}((0,+\infty))=B$. In particular, $f$ and its derivatives of all orders are $0$ in $\mathbb R^n \backslash B$. Define a function $g: M \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) = f\circ \phi(x)$ for $x\in U$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x\not\in U$.

**Question: Is $g$ a smooth function?** I can prove $g$ is continuous. Also,  $g|_U$ is smooth by definition. I believe $g$ should also be smooth, but I don't know how to show it.

I'm interested in the question, because in Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, in the proof of the existence of partition of unity, he defined a function similar to $g$ except $U$ is chosen to be a **regular coordinate ball**, is this case it is easy to show $g$ is smooth.  I wonder whether the condition that the coordinate ball $U$ is regular is only technical.

Comment: Given that $\phi$ is a smooth coordinate chart, is not $g$ smooth on $U$ by definition?

Comment: @ElliotG Yeah, $g$ is smooth on $U$, but I don't know whether $g$ is smooth on $M$.

Comment: Yes, it's locally smooth at every point because $U$ is open.

Comment: Hint: Construct a counter-examples when $n=1$, $M={\mathbb R}$, $U=B=(-1,1)$ and $\phi: B\to B$ is a suitable diffeomorphism (you would have to figure out which one to take).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I see it now.

Comment: Then you can write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Berci But $M \backslash U$ is not open.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have written the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde f:(-\infty,1) \to [0, 1)$ be a smooth function such that $\tilde f|_{(-\infty,-1]} = \{0\} $, $\tilde f|_{(-1,1)}: (-1,1) \to (0,1)$ is diffeomorphism and $\tilde f$ is strictly increasing on $(-1, 1)$. Let $\phi:  (0,1) \to (-1,1)$ be the diffeomorphism $(\tilde f|_{(-1,1)})^{-1}$, then $\tilde f\circ \phi (x) = x$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Let $\tilde g: (-\infty,1) \to \mathbb R$ be the function that $\tilde g(x) = \tilde f\circ \phi(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $\tilde g(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then the one sided derivatives of $\tilde g$ at $0$ are different and thus $\tilde g$ is not differentiable at $0$.

To construct a counterexample, we only need to let $M = (-\infty, 1), \ B= (-1,1),\ U = (0,1)$ and  $f(x) = \tilde f(x)$ for $x < 0$. Then $\tilde g(x) = g(x)$ for $x < \phi^{-1}(0)$, and $g$ is not differentiable at $0$.